# Count specific rows to match the query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named **results** retrieved and displayed as follows

[image: Working table]

the columns sub1 to sub2 represents the subject names and the rows have values scored by the students

While the information is retrieved from the db, I also need to count in how many subjects did a student score less than 40 for example, Tom scored less than 40 in 2 subjects and the result would look like as follows

[image: Working table]

Please help how to write a query to display the last column

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL has the convenient ability to treat boolean comparisons as integers.  Here is a pretty simple way to express your logic:

```
select id, students, sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4, sub5, sub6,
       ((sub1 < 40) + (sub2 < 40) + (sub3 < 40) + (sub4 < 40) + (sub5 < 40) + (sub6 < 40)
       ) as FailedIn 
from table t;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Normalizing your table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) would have made this much easier, but even without changing its structure, you can get this result with some `case` statements:

```
SELECT id, students, 
       sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4, sub5, sub6,
       CASE WHEN sub1 < 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN sub2 < 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN sub3 < 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN sub4 < 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN sub5 < 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN sub6 < 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "Failed IN"
FROM   my_table
```